# AngularJS - pass parameter to another directive atribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this simple directive:

```js
angular.module(appName).directive('appSearch', AppSearchDirective)

function AppSearchDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'app/directives/app-search.html',
        scope: {
            appSearchText: '@',
            appSearchCommand: '@' 
        },
    }
}
```

```html
<a title='appSearchText' ui-sref='appSearchCommand'>
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</a>
```

I want to send those parameters to the attributes title and ui-sref. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

1- use

```
<a title="{{$ctrl.appSearchText}}" ui-sref="$ctrl.appSearchCommand">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</a>
```

2- in your directive you need to pass parameters like

```
<app-search app-search-text={{$ctrl.myText}} app-search-command={{$ctrl.myCommand}}></app-search>
```